# Where should I post a question regarding web design?

Tags: support, questions, specific-question, asking-questions, site-recommendation

Is there a StackExchange site appropriate to ask a question about web design?

I'm needing some suggestions about which colors to use for a very dark themed website, where should I ask this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Two options:

1. [Graphic Design Stack Exchange](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/website-design+color) ([FAQ](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/faq) - 22 [website-design + color](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bwebsite-design%5D+%5Bcolor%5D+closed%3A0) questions, including [one that might be a duplicate of yours](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/9252/how-to-design-sites-with-dark-colours-red-and-black-palette))
2. [User Experience Stack Exchange](https://ux.stackexchange.com/) ([FAQ](https://ux.stackexchange.com/faq) - 21 [color scheme](https://ux.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcolor-scheme%5D+closed%3A0) questions)

Read both sites' FAQs carefully and search for similar questions before you ask your own.

Comment: Thanks, I'll probably use the Graphic Design one

Answer (score 3):

At the moment, the question is too broad for most every site dealing with this subject.  If you could narrow down your question a bit...

- If your question was about improving the kind of user experience a user would receive with a dark-themed website, and could provide screenshots, then perhaps [User Experience](http://ux.stackexchange.com) would be a good fit.
- If your question was about *why* people prefer to do dark themed websites, then perhaps [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) would be a good fit.

General opinion-poll type questions are off topic for most any question on Stack Exchange.  For some background on that, check out [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).